# Django password hashes in database

Tags: argon2

can someone explain to me why django saves the hash in the database as`argon2$argon2id$v=19$m=102400,t=2,p=8$...` and not `$argon2id$v=19$m=102400,t=2,p=8$...`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I suppose this would be more on-topic on [security.se](https://security.stackexchange.com/) or even StackOverflow, as it's essentially about how software **uses** an existing piece of cryptographic software in a black-box manner.

**TL; DR** the leading `argon2` identifies Django's wrapper class around the `argon2-cffi` library. The remainder is that library's output.

First, according to the [Django documentation on password storage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/passwords/#how-django-stores-passwords), the format they claim to use is the following:

```
<algorithm>$<iterations>$<salt>$<hash>
```

However this format is limiting, in that it assumes that each algorithm has exactly one parameter each for `iterations`, `salt`, and `hash`. I do suppose this format would be correct if you used the default, PBKDF2-based, password hashing - less so if using something like Argon2, with its plethora of parameters.

In general then, the format it actually uses is:

```
<algorithm>$<output>
```

Where `algorithm` uniquely identifies the specific implementation (in terms of a Python class) of password hashing which was used, and `output` is simply that one's output. Indeed you can observe this behaviour e.g. [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3b79dab19a2300a4884a3d81baa6c7c1f2dee059/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py#L145), where you see that Django first checks the first component of the stored value to identify the wrapper class to use, which is [later](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3b79dab19a2300a4884a3d81baa6c7c1f2dee059/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py#L58) used to compare a hash with a supplied password.

Then your observed output becomes clear. The first `argon2` identifies [Django's Argon2 wrapper](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3b79dab19a2300a4884a3d81baa6c7c1f2dee059/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py#L357), and `argon2id$v=19$m=102400,t=2,p=8$...` is its output.

Following the chain a bit more we learn that [Django relies on the](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/passwords/#using-argon2-with-django) `argon2-cffi` library for Argon2 hashing, which indeed [produces output similar to what you observed.](https://pypi.org/project/argon2-cffi/)